# Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported Entity Framework 5

Tags: devexpress, entity-framework-5, datasource

I have a devexpress GridControl for which I am setting it's datasource like so:

```
var regs = (from vcap in context.chaps
                             select vcap);

gridControl1.DataSource = new BindingList<chaps>(regs.ToList());
```

But when I use the grid, rows I add or delete don't get saved, only changes to the initial rows get saved.

If I do this:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = context.chaps.Local;
```

I don't get any rows, and `AddNewRow` doesn't even add a new row visually.

If I do this:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = context.chaps.ToList();
```

I get the rows and can save changes to them; rows get deteled visually but not in the db, and can't `AddNewRow`.

If I do this:

```
gridControl1.DataSource = context.chaps;
```

I get this exception:

```
Data binding directly to a store query (DbSet, DbQuery, DbSqlQuery) is not supported. Instead populate a DbSet with data, for example by calling Load on the DbSet, and then bind to local data. For WPF bind to DbSet.Local. For WinForms bind to DbSet.Local.ToBindingList().
```

but context.chaps.Local does not have a `ToBindingList` method either.

I don't think this is a problem of devexpress, but rather I'm not getting how to set a datasource properly. Is there a way to get a `context.chaps.Local.ToBindingList()` equivalent?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`context.chaps.Local` is an `ObservableCollection<T>`. But `ToBindingList` is not a method of `ObservableCollection<T>` but an extension method in `DbExtensions`:

```cs
public static BindingList<T> ToBindingList<T>(
    this ObservableCollection<T> source) where T : class;
```

In order to use this method and see it with Intellisense you need to include the corresponding namespace in the code file where you try to call `ToBindingList()`:

```cs
using System.Data.Entity;
```

Comment: So I did 
gridControl1.DataSource = DbExtensions.ToBindingList<capitulo>(context.capitulo.Local);
which totally works! I can add, modify and delete. Except that it doesn't load all the rows I have initially (my datagrid is empty). Any idea how to do that? Or did I misunderstood the answer?

Comment: @user2414791: Standard syntax when using extension methods is like with normal instance methods: `gridControl1.DataSource = context.capitulo.Local.ToBindingList();`. But I don't think it will fix the problem. Of course you must still use `regs.ToList()` or `regs.Load()` or `context.chaps.Load()` to load anything from the DB. `Local` doesn't run a query, it just provides the entities that already have been loaded before as an `ObservableCollection`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have load all the rows before you bind your data source with to binding list.

`context.chaps.load`    'load your data 
`gridcontrol1.datasource = context.chaps.Local.ToBindingList()` ' this will load records on the grid. also give you a new row to add new or you are allowed to update the grid too.